# Cplex opl run doesn't answer when I add easy code

Tags: constraints, mathematical-optimization, cplex, opl

I have a small project with CPLEX OPL. In my model, I have almost 40 constraints. It works properly and gives me objective function value as 90. Objective function is:

```
 maximize sum(k in konteyner, s in sandik, x in ex)  sx[k][s][x]+
          sum(k in konteyner, s in sandik, y in vay) sy[k][s][y]+
          sum(k in konteyner, s in sandik, z in zed) sz[k][s][z];
```

In this situation my model works with other all constraints. However, when I add a constraint that doesn't constrain anything, my model works but doesn't give an answer. Finally, it say that "OPL run doesn't answer." But, this constraint cannot affect anything.

The constraint that is added is below:

```
forall(s1 in sandik, s2 in sandik, k in konteyner, x in ex, y in vay, z in 
zed: s1 < s2)
{   
sx[k][s1][x] + sy[k][s1][y] + sz[k][s1][z] + sx[k][s2][x] + sy[k][s2][y] + 
sz[k][s2][z] <= 99999999 ;
}
```

Note: sx,sy,sz are boolean decision variables.

Note2: Normally in last constraint, value isn't 99999. I wanted to it doesn't constrain anything for just now.

Note3: Normally value is 5. When I make it 5, it still doesn't work.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: How big are the sets/ranges 'konteyner', 'sandik' etc? You are trying to add a constraint for each combination of their values. So if there are about 10 values in each you will be generating of the order of 1000000 constraints. If those sets/ranges are bigger, the number of constraints generated will get very big very fast

Comment: You are right. My ranges were too big and computer cannot compensate it. I figured out. When I tried it with smal ranges, it run. Thank you so much.